# painting multiple images to a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm having an issue with drawing multiple images from objects on to a custom JPanel.  I've been able to successfully paint one image representation of an object on the JPanel.  Adding more objects only paints on top of the other Image, I believe, since they use the same Graphics2D object.

So I've decided to create a custom JComponent that contains the Shapes, Image, and Object, but unfortunately it isn't working any better.  My thinking was this would allow the JPanel to use a for loop for each object and create a new Graphics2D object to paint with.

This is for a game I'm programming, FYI.  The objects I'm trying to paint are the units on screen that need to be manipulated.

```
public class ShipGraphic extends JComponent{

private Shape       shipShape, combatShape;
private Image       shipImage;
private ImageIcon   si;
private int         shipX = 0, shipY = 0, shipW, shipH, combatH, combatW, combatR;
private Ship        ship;

public ShipGraphic(Ship ship)
{
    this.ship = ship;
    setImageIcon();
    shipImage = si.getImage();
    shipW = shipImage.getWidth(null);
    shipH = shipImage.getHeight(null);
    combatH = shipH * 2;
    combatW = shipW * 2;
    combatR = -(shipW * 2);
    shipShape = new Rectangle2D.Double(shipX, shipY, shipW, shipH);
    combatShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(combatR, combatR, combatW, combatH);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g4 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.drawImage(shipImage, shipX, shipY, null);
    g3.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    g3.drawRect(shipX, shipY, shipW, shipH);
    g4.draw(combatShape);
}
```

The ShipGraphic uses a Rectangle to check if the user has clicked on the Image and will use the Circle to determine if it intersects another rectangle for combat.  These two shapes are drawn opaque under the Image.

The custom JPanel then adds them to the panel using this for loop:

```
    for ( Ship s : sector.getShips() )
    {
        ShipGraphic ship = new ShipGraphic(s);
    }
```

Comment: `"Adding more objects only paints on top of the other Image, ..."` Yes, this is the expected behavior. What different behavior are you trying to achieve? I can't find this anywhere in your question. Also note that you're creating several Graphics2D variables, but they all refer to the same Graphics object and so you achieve nothing by doing this. Are you familiar with the distinction between an object and a reference variable as this is quite an important distinction and gets to the core of Java?

Comment: I'm still very much a novice right now so most of my knowledge of Swing has come from trial and error and reviewing example implementations online.  It seems to me that when I attempted to use the same Graphics2D from Graphics g, I couldn't achieve any images on screen.  So from that I assumed there was a need to create a new Graphics2D variable for each image I need.  What I am trying to accomplish is be able to draw an Image for the Ship and Shapes that will handle the mouse events and intersections for each Ship in the Panel.  however, I've only been able to achieve a single Image so far.

Comment: Your assumptions are very much incorrect. You really need to go to the Swing graphics tutorials. You're just throwing code at the wall and see if any of it sticks, and that's a poor plan for learning this difficult subject. Study from the pros at the tutorials.

Comment: What tutorials are you referring to and where can I find them?

Comment: These: 1) [The Java Tutorials, The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), 2) [The Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), 3) [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), and 4) [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Adding more objects only paints on top of the other Image, I believe, since they use the same Graphics2D object.

The problem is not because you use the same Graphic object. All Swing components on a given frame are painted with the same Graphics object. If they paint on top of each other then that would be because you don't specify a proper x/y position for each object.

> So I've decided to create a custom JComponent that contains the Shapes

That is a good approach. However, in this case you would always paint your object at location (0, 0) of the component. Then you would position each component by invoking `setLocation(...)` on the component.

You would also need to override the getPreferredSize() method of the component to make sure it returns the appropriate size of your component.

The example code you posted has a typing mistake. Get rid of the "s" on super.paintComponents(g).

Comment: I think I understand.  I'll need to add a X, Y location for each object so that the Graphic object can refer to this and keep track of each individual Ship's location.  This way, the player can move ships independent of each other since the Ship object would be used as the logic for its location on screen.  This sound better?  And thanks for your feedback!